# Multiple loads of property tree xml-parser exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, boost, boost-propertytree

I am using property tree xml-parsing to edit some settings for my application
I created a struct default-settings

```
struct default_settings
{
    std::string imPath;          
    std::string calPath;
    std::string solPath;

    void load(const std::string &filename);
    void save(const std::string &filename,const std::string &image_path,const std::string &cal_path,const std::string &sol_path);

};

void default_settings::save(const std::string &filename,const std::string &image_path,const std::string &cal_path,const std::string &sol_path)
{

    ptree pt;

    pt.put("default.image-path", image_path);
    pt.put("default.cal-path", cal_path);
    pt.put("default.sol-path", sol_path);

    write_xml(filename, pt);    
}
void default_settings::load(const std::string &filename)
{

    ptree pt;

    read_xml(filename, pt);

    imPath = pt.get<std::string>("default.image-path");
    calPath = pt.get<std::string>("default.cal-path");
    solPath = pt.get<std::string>("default.sol-path");


}
```

and I access the variables: imPath, calPath, .. etc
by creating a global variable in my application default_settings ds
and calling them through this variable (ds.imPath)

The weird thing is that it works when the load is done once but I get an exception

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error> > at memory location 0x0016bf54..
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: have you tried debugging it? are you using the _same property tree_ as the target each time? What is in the injected error information?

Comment: as u see I create a new ptree everytime I access the function load

Comment: I tried using 1 ptree as a global variable and clear() it everytime I enter the function but still the same problem !

Comment: well, without any calls to `load` I couldn't assume that was what you meant. It starts to look interesting though, could you post a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem? If that's a '_lot of_' work, rest assured that 90% of the time it will also tell you the problem when we couldn't possibly see it

Comment: After a lot of debugging it seems that the problem is exactly in the multiple calls of the load function!

Comment: if I use my 'psychic debugging' goggles, I'd say 'Undefined Behaviour'. I suspect that you might simply be using a stale reference to the filename or something silly like that. Try running your program under <strike>valgrind</strike> _similar tools on windows(?)_ and/or tracing a few variables to the console for verification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in using const std::string as a parameter!